# The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s)

Tags: android

having an issue checking null element in String array.

> The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null

onCreateView

```
private String[] FilePathStrings;
private File[] listFile;

....  
    listFile = file.listFiles();

    FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];


if(listFile.length == null){

                //   Do Something

                }else {

                  //   Do Something
                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` cannot be compared to `null`, which is a null reference to an object. Compare with zero instead.

Answer (score 2):

length on array `listFile.length` returns integer (`int`) a primitive data type value and that can never be null (It's not an object to be null). So you can never use an `==` operator to compare `int` value with `null` as primitive data  types can never be null and are assigned default values and it is 0 in case of int.

Answer (score 1):

An int can never be null, as it is a primitive, not an object. Consider checking instead `== 0`.

For more information about primitive types in Java and their default values, you can look in the documentation shown here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html